# Why doesn't Gnome Terminal support dark theme?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-terminal

In my work laptop I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1 and I am not being able to configure Gnome Terminal to use the dark theme.

In my home computer I am using Arch Linux and Gnome Terminal has a checkbox that allows me to switch to the dark theme.
At first thought that it may be caused by Arch using a newer version of Gnome Terminal than Ubuntu. But the thing is that before Arch I was running Debian 8, and I had the same option available in Gnome Terminal.

Why is this option not available in Ubuntu?

Comment: Just for fun: Make sure to check out Linus's opinion about the "Emo mode": https://plus.google.com/+LinusTorvalds/posts/Wh3qTjMMbLC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why? Because <s>Ubuntu</s> GNOME developers decided to rip off that option saying ["It's more trouble than it's worth"](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/commit/?id=5f6c514) . But it [will be available from Gnome Terminal 3.19](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/commit/?id=7d5fc06), which means we will see it in 16.10. (Thanks to egmont for correcting me on that it wasn't Ubuntus decision)

But you can enable Dark theme variant using

```
GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark gnome-terminal
```

command.

If you want you can even change the `EXEC` line in `.desktop` file of gnome terminal

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark gnome-terminal
```

Another option is to enable Dark variant for all applications using **Gnome Tweak Tool**. Install it, open, and in General Tab select **Use Dark Theme** option

Check this question for more

- [GTK - Enable/set dark theme on a per-application basis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14129/gtk-enable-set-dark-theme-on-a-per-application-basis)

Comment: It wasn't Ubuntu ripping off this option. Mainstream gnome-terminal removed it temporarily due to certain technical problems. It's back and I think it's going to be there in Yakkety.

Comment: Do you have the bug link @egmont? I thought it was Ubuntu. Thanks for the info

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to modify the `.desktop` file for Gnome Terminal so it always uses the dark theme.

BTW, sad to see Ubuntu removing this configuration option :(

Comment: See the links in the commit messages of https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/commit/?id=5f6c514 and https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/commit/?id=7d5fc06.

Comment: @crbelaus Once again, it was not Ubuntu removing this option.

Comment: @egmont Thank you very much for correct information. Will you allow me to put the information in my answer  to correct it? Or if you prefer you can write your own answer.

Comment: @egmont Edited the answer. Hope It's correct now. Thank you again for giving the right info :)

Comment: Wow! I'm even more baffled after seeing this comes from vanilla Gnome. Bad decision IMHO. Thank you very much for the information @egmont !!!

Comment: It required work in the underlying libraries to work perfectly, which was done for the GNOME 3.20 release as far as I remember.